# Print pv output (stderr) to file

Tags: pipe, stderr, pv

How can I print the [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) output of [pv](/questions/tagged/pv) to a file? For example:

```
timeout 5s dd if=/dev/random | pv -r > /dev/null
[ 505kiB/s]
```

The rate line output is "updated" over the course of my five second timeout. I tried this but it does not work (log is empty):

```
timeout 5s dd if=/dev/random | pv -r > /dev/null 2> rates.log
```

I believe it has something to do with *carriage returns* in the [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) output, but after an hour I am stuck. Ideally my log file would have multiple lines each time [pv](/questions/tagged/pv) prints a new value:

```
[ 505kiB/s]
[ 498kiB/s]
[ 542kiB/s]
[ 513kiB/s]
[ 509kiB/s]
```

UPDATE:

To get the content into a file as I described above I had to use [stdbuf](/questions/tagged/stdbuf) though I'm not sure why it is required ([tr](/questions/tagged/tr) alone didn't work, the file will be empty without [stdbuf](/questions/tagged/stdbuf)):

```
timeout 5s dd if=/dev/random | pv -fr > /dev/null 2> >(stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' > rates.log)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man pv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html):

> -f, --force
>
> Force output.  Normally, pv will not output any visual display
>                 if standard error is not a terminal.  This option forces it to
>                 do so.

Since `rates.log` isn't a terminal, you need to do `pv -fr` instead of `pv -r`.

Comment: I posted a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901856/bash-process-substitution-behaves-differently-than-named-pipe) if you are interested. Thanks!