# Bash process substitution behaves differently than named pipe?

Tags: named-pipes, tr, process-substitution, pv

Kind of a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864319/print-pv-output-stderr-to-file). I use bash process substitution expecting to see 5 lines of output (corresponding to 5s timeout) however I only see 4 lines:

```
timeout 5s dd if=/dev/random | pv -fr > /dev/null 2> >(tr '\r' '\n' >&2)
[5.42kiB/s]
[1.89kiB/s]
[5.36kiB/s]
[2.41kiB/s]
```

However if I place a named pipe in the middle I do get the 5 lines as expected. First shell:

```
mkfifo testfifo
cat testfifo | tr '\r' '\n' >&2
```

Second shell:

```
timeout 5s dd if=/dev/random | pv -fr > /dev/null 2> testfifo
```

Output from first shell (5 lines):

```
[3.79kiB/s]
[3.12kiB/s]
[ 4.4kiB/s]
[2.05kiB/s]
[5.58kiB/s]
```

Why do I not get 5 lines when using bash process substitution?

**BONUS**

I also attempted to dump the output to a file instead of [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) however this gave me an empty log file:

```
timeout 5s dd if=/dev/random | pv -fr > /dev/null 2> >(tr '\r' '\n' > rates.log)
```

I discovered that when using [stdbuf](/questions/tagged/stdbuf) my `rates.log` file contain multiple lines of output as originally expected:

```
timeout 5s dd if=/dev/random | pv -fr > /dev/null 2> >(stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' > rates.log)
```

Why was the stdbuf required for my [tr](/questions/tagged/tr)? (also notice the file contains 4 lines so this call structure likely suffers the same problem as above)

Comment: I think this is just a race condition. If you change `5s` to `4.99s`, I expect both will only give you 4 lines, and similarly `5.01s` to cause both to give you 5 lines.